# Update a list of Dict based on another Dict

Tags: python

I have a dict as follows.

```
dict = {'P': ['Demo'], 'Q': ['PMS']}
```

And I have a list of Dict as follows.

```
all = [{'Name': 'PMS'}, {'Name': 'Demo'}]
```

I need to have the dict's respective value in all as bellow.

```
new_list = [{'Name': 'PMS','Code': 'Q'}, {'Name': 'Demo','Code': 'P'}]
```

Comment: Both `dict` and `all` are builtin functions. Don't use them to name variables or they will mask those functions

Comment: look up lambda and the zip function.

Comment: suresh - I saw that you accepted my answer and then afterwards I saw a problem with it, which I have since corrected. Please ensure that you have the latest version. (See my comment under the answer for more details.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific case, given that the values are just strings and therefore hashable objects, you can use a dictionary of reverse mappings.  Be aware that it could not be used if the values were not hashable.

```
dct = {'P': ['Demo'], 'Q': ['PMS']}
all = [{'Name': 'PMS'}, {'Name': 'Demo'}]

reverse_mapping = {v[0]:k for k, v in dct.items()}

new_list = [d.copy() for d in all]
for d in new_list:
    d['Code'] = reverse_mapping[d['Name']]

print(new_list)
```

This gives:

```
[{'Name': 'PMS', 'Code': 'Q'}, {'Name': 'Demo', 'Code': 'P'}]
```

Comment: Note: my original version of this answer used `new_list = all.copy()`. This would have resulted in modifying the sub-dictionaries of the input list. I have modified it to do a deeper copy (`[d.copy() for d in all]`), in order to avoid that problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
dct = {'P': ['Demo'], 'Q': ['PMS']}
all_ = [{'Name': 'PMS'}, {'Name': 'Demo'}]

out = [dict(**l, Code=next(k for k, v in dct.items() if l['Name'] in v)) for l in all_]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[{'Name': 'PMS', 'Code': 'Q'}, {'Name': 'Demo', 'Code': 'P'}]
```

---

Or: you can make temporary dictionary:

```
tmp = {v[0]:k for k, v in dct.items()}
out = [dict(**l, Code=tmp[l['Name']]) for l in all_]
print(out)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make an inverted dictionary of codes, then go through the list of dictionaries and add the codes in:

```py
codes = {"P": ["Demo"], "Q": ["PMS"]}

lst = [{"Name": "PMS"}, {"Name": "Demo"}]

inverted_codes = {value: key for key, values in codes.items() for value in values}
# {'Demo': 'P', 'PMS': 'Q'}

for dic in lst:
    code = dic["Name"]
    dic["Code"] = inverted_codes[code]

print(lst)
```

**Output**

```
[{'Name': 'PMS', 'Code': 'Q'}, {'Name': 'Demo', 'Code': 'P'}]
```